# Concerning iterating over locals

Tags: python-2.7

In python it is common to run `for i in s:` to iterate over a string, s. It is also possible to access variables using the local function.

```
s = "qwer"
for i in s:
    print i
    del locals()['s']
```

I expect that this code should print "q", then delete the variable s, making the next time we evaluate i in s to cause an error. The i variable should not be resolved. However, the output from this code snippet is to print q and then to print w, then to have a key error. Thus, the locals dictionary does not have an s variable. Therefore, the only problem is when we call the locals dictionary in the second time through the loop. How is s still stored even though we deleted it from the locals variable? Doesn't locals actually store the variables, or is it just the references?

Comment: `del` just removes the idenfier from the scope and decrements the reference count of the underlying object - the `for` loop keeps a reference to the underlying object, it doesn't access it via the identifier each time the loop repeats.

Comment: Well that answers the question. Is there a way to delete the underlying object?

Comment: No, that sticks around at least until its reference count falls to zero